# Getting an error on running HCatalog

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

```
A = LOAD 'eventnew.txt' USING HCatalogLoader();
```

> 2015-07-08 19:56:34,875 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve HCatalogLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
>   Details at logfile: /home/KS5023833/pig_1436364102374.log

Then I tried

```
 A = LOAD 'xyz' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```

This is also not working.

> 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

what is the problem?  I am a novice in Hadoop.

Comment: when you launched the `grunt>` shell, did you type `$ pig -useHCatalog` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by GoBrewers14 you must start pig with -useHCatalog. If you are running a Pig script an alternative is to determine the location of the HCatalog jar and add a REGISTER statement with the path of the jar to the top of your script

Example:

`REGISTER /home/user/Installations/hive-0.11.0-bin/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hcatalog-core-0.11.0.jar;`

of course your path/version may be different.

Comment: Trivial, but just to clarify for novices: Where you would normally just call `pig` you can now instead simply call `pig -useHCatalog` (Mind the capitalization.). So this can be used for running in the terminal, or for calling a script with `pig -useHCatalog -f yourscript.pig` Of course this is also required for any script containing `HCatStorer`.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, fixed it as following:
Start pig using "-useHCatalog" option.

pig -useHCatalog

then try :
A = LOAD 'eventnew.txt' USING HCatalogLoader();

Answer (score 0):

You can now launch pig shell just by using command to use HCatalog-

```
pig -useHCatalog
grunt> a = load 'table' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```